# NGINX redirect HTTP to HTTPS with angular hash-tag syntax

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have a server I want to run only in HTTPS. I'm running Node and Nginx on Amazon AMI.

To redirect to HTTPS I simply put this in my nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_server;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

And then the SSL is configured. However when Angular urls such as `http://www.mypage.com/#/whatever` comes in, the resulting redirect is `https://www.mypage.com/` without the vital Angular syntax.

How can I make it work for the Angular hash-tag syntax? Nginx version is 1.6.2.

Thanks

Comment: I think the whole idea behind hash is that it never sent to the server, hence it is not exist on the request Nginx getting. try a workaround with cookies maybe.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that it's never sent?

Comment: Yes. see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible.
Im not going to talk about nginx best approach of redirecting to different protocol.

The problem is that hash is never sent to server.

Every browser that i know will ignore the hash portion in the URL.

So if for example you will send this URL to example server:

```
http://localhost/6/?e#hash_here
```

The request will send:

```
http://localhost/6/?e
```

The browser simply strip it off.

From JS's view i will recommend using some `EventListener` on `onhashchange`,
so you can intercept all requests and store the `location.hash` in a cookie.

Now when this request will arrive to the server you will be able to use nginx's `$http_cookie` (it will be something like `angularLocation=#/whatever` so use some regex to find if it is exist)

Comment: Hi, ok that is lame but thanks for your answer. Cheers!